# Weird character after do changes using perl command

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

Good day.

Let say my file content as below::

```
java ${AGENT_JAVAOPTS} -Xmx2560m com.xxx.xxx.xxx.AgentXX   -inifile ${XXX_AGENT_INI}  -queues winall,dustat,envstat,netstat,iostat,winconfig,netwarestat,netwareconfig,pawmin,paw15,db2,sqlserver,vmstatvmw2,vmstatvm2,netstatvm,netstatvmw,vmstatvm,vmstatvmw,iostatvm,iostatvmw,envstatvm,envstatvmw,vmscpu,vmsdisk,vmsmem,vmstatvcw,process,winprocess  -log xxx0202.'$DotDate'.log -AgentName xxx0202
```

Then, I try to change the strings after '-queue' to "winall,process,winconfig,vmscpu,vmstat,dustat", which I using below command in UNIX::

```
perl -pi -e 'tr/winall,dustat,envstat,netstat,iostat,winconfig,netwarestat,netwareconfig,pawmin,paw15,db2,sqlserver,vmstatvmw2,vmstatvm2,netstatvm,netstatvmw,vmstatvm,vmstatvmw,iostatvm,iostatvmw,envstatvm,envstatvmw,vmscpu,vmsdisk,vmsmem,vmstatvcw,process,winprocess/winall,process,winconfig,vmscpu,vmstat,dustat/' file
```

However, it produced an output with a weird character as below::

```
jaia ${AGENT_JAVAOPTS} -Xtxtt60t u,t.itt.ott.cotau,.At,ncDP   -iniail, ${SRM_AGENT_INI}  -tr,r,o winall,procac,,niocac,n,cocac,i,ocac,winu,nait,n,cwat,ocac,n,cwat,u,nait,tawtin,tawtt,ptt,otlo,ti,t,itocacitwt,itocacitt,n,cocacit,n,cocacitw,itocacit,itocacitw,i,ocacit,i,ocacitw,,niocacit,,niocacitw,itoutr,itopiot,itot,t,itocaciuw,tt,u,oo,wintt,u,oo  -l,t tlp0t0t.'$D,cDac,'.l,t -At,ncNat, tlp0t0t
```

How come it produce the output like above?

The output suppose to be as:

```
java ${AGENT_JAVAOPTS} -Xmx2560m com.xxx.xxx.xxx.AgentXX   -inifile ${XXX_AGENT_INI} -queues winall,process,winconfig,vmscpu,vmstat,dustat -log xxx0202.'$DotDate'.log -AgentName xxx0202
```

Need assistance for this issue.

Comment: If any of the following answer helped you in your goal please accept/upvote the answer for closure by ticking right sign besides the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr///` is the transliteration, not substitution.

It replaces the first character of SEARCHLIST with the first character of REPLACEMENTLIST (similar to `y///` in `sed`), and so on. What you need is the substitution `s///`. See [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop) for details.

Comment: Thanks @choroba , it helps =)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/(^.*-queues)(.*)/\1 winall,process,winconfig,vmscpu,vmstat,dustat/' inputfile
java ${AGENT_JAVAOPTS} -Xmx2560m com.xxx.xxx.xxx.AgentXX -inifile ${XXX_AGENT_INI} -queues winall,process,winconfig,vmscpu,vmstat,dustat
```

Here, the line is divided into two chunks using backrefrencing, 1st is from start till `-queues` and 2nd is from that point until the end.

Or you can use `awk` to store the text into a variable and use it while replacement. Here you can change the text by changing the value of variable `var` .

```
awk -v FS='-queues' -v var='winall,process,winconfig,vmscpu,vmstat,dustat' '{print $1 FS var}' inputfile
```

Comment: Thanks for this sed command, it give me an idea...but the string after which is -log xxx0202.'$DotDate'.log -AgentName xxx0202 are disappeared after run this command.

Comment: @Azizul , in the command I have provided only partial input , you need to update the text after `\1 ` as per your need.

Comment: Thanks, it helps =)